# Use PATCH-request in Swagger Petstore API?

Tags: request, patch, put

It is my understandning that the petstore API is an example of a well-structured API: https://petstore.swagger.io/#/

In this API there is a call: https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/updatePetWithForm which is POST-request.

This is the structure of the pet resource:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
  },
  "name": "doggie",
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

It looks like we are updating parts of an existing resource (not in its entirety, there is another request for that https://petstore.swagger.io/#/pet/updatePet), so why is this not a PATCH-request?

I have tried to understand this using resources found online, to no avail.